# Delayed deployment of InfoSphere Streams Operators and Runtime 'tags' deployment

Tags: infosphere-spl, ibm-infosphere

I'd like to know if two functionalities are available in infosphere streams, but I could not find it anywhere else.

1) To the best of my knowledge, when an InfoSphere Streams Application starts, all of the operators are deployed on the hosts in the cluster. Is it possible to deploy specific operator per results of previous Operator(s)? So that the deployment is happening during a job (and not only when a host fails).

2) Also, to the best of my knowledge, tags exists which allow specifying which Operators will be deployed to which hosts. Is it possible to change hosts tags during a Job runtime? Adding to question (1), is it possible that on runtime, I will deploy an Operator to a specific machine based on computations that occurred during the job?

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answers to your questions ...

1.) operators can be placed relative to placement of other operators, but not based upon the results of an operator's execution.

2.) There is currently no way for a running operator to change host tags based upon its calculations.

The tags can be changed on a host while a job is running, but this must be done through administrator operations.  Then the PEs must be stopped and restarted to take advantage of this new tagging configuration.

Comment: Thanks you very much.